No reconoce un indice en un arreglo
Pese a hacer una consulta correcta a una tabla, no pasa el arreglo al HTML y el sistema devuelve un error de

Undefined array key "flag"

Esta es la consulta en el controller:
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $query = $db->table('languajes');
    $query->select
    ('
        languajes.id,
        languajes.codigo,
        languajes.descripcion,
        languajes.flag
    ');
    $query->where(['languajes.codigo' => auth()->user()->locale]);

    $query = $query->get();
    $languaje = $query->getResultArray();

Añado la impresión de la variable $languaje y el resultado es correcto:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 35 [codigo] => eu [descripcion] => ee.uu [flag] => http://localhost/empresa/public/img/flags/estados-unidos.png ) )

Se le pasa el arreglo a la vista:
$data = [
        'languaje'          => $languaje
    ];
    return view('productos/index', $data);

Sin embargo, al imprimirlo en HTML así:
<?= $languaje['flag']; ?>

Me devuelve el error:

Undefined array key "flag"

¿Alguna idea de por qué pasa?

Hola Jota, si te fijas en la impresión podes ver que los datos están en la posición [0], es decir que para acceder a estos tenes que hacer $languaje[0]['flag']

Cierto Marcos: Array ( [0] =>Esto no me había pasado con otros arreglos. Gracias!
